# setup.py cannot find numpy headers

Tags: python, c, numpy, setup.py

To include C extensions, the setup.py to build my repo looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("my_module", 
                  sources=["my_module.cc"],
                  include_dirs=[np.get_include()]),
    ],
)
```

but despite including the path to the numpy headers, running `python setup.py install` results in the error `fatal error: 'arrayobject.h' file not found` because my_module.cc has `#include <arrayobject.h>`.

I've gone through dozens of related SO and GitHub issues, all suggesting the `include_dirs=[np.get_include()]` workaround I've already implemented. The numpy path is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/`, and yes I've confirmed the headers are indeed there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

On my system the header file is at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h`, so the solution is to instead do `include_dirs=[os.path.join(np.get_include(), 'numpy')]`.

Comment: Alternatively, in the C file specify `#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"`